# An antonym for "premium"

Tags: single-word-requests

More specifically, in economics and finance for example, there is the "equity premium puzzle" ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equity_premium_puzzle)). This is the puzzle of why equities seem to enjoy a "premium" relative to (government) bonds.

We could therefore also refer to this puzzle as the "bond **__** puzzle"? What is the best word to fill in the blank here? I can think of only "dispremium" but I don't think that's a proper word.

Comment: In this context, wouldn't the opposite of a *premium* be a *discount*?

Comment: Peter Shor is right. In finance, opposite of premium is discount.

Comment: Yes I think *discount* is correct.

Answer (score 1):

As the comments note, an appropriate antonym is "discount":

> premium — additional sum: a sum of money paid in addition to a normal wage, rate, price, or other amount
>
> discount — reduction in price: a reduction in the usual price of something

Answer (score -1):

**Disfavor** would seem to be a decent suggestion here.

I think that **premium** in this sense is referring to a preference or demand.

Since you are looking for the opposite of that preference, I would say disfavor.

Some other terms like **discrimination** could be elected, too.  Investors are discriminating against bonds in favor of equities.

Likewise, **bias** is another useful term.  (The only caveat is that bias can mean both for and against.)

Additionally, **derision** could be applied.  Investors are contemptuous of bonds and it is puzzling.

And, lastly, **distrust**.  In context, you are saying that investors don't inherently trust bonds despite their performance advantage.